# Open-source/Free batch image/IG-post/banner generator

Tags: images, artificial-intelligence, marketing, instagram

I am looking for an open source image/IG-post/banner generator, very much like DynaPictures, but free or open-source.. Is there one?

I especially need the bulk generation feature, where I can have a spreadsheet in which one column would contain the text I would need in the output, and subsequent columns would contain the url of any images I would want to include in the output.

Even better: if the images themselves can be generated from the keywords with AI like in https://wepik.com/ai, that would be great.

Possible types that I am ok with: A CLI program, a PHP/Javascript library, a google sheets plugin, a GUI app, a web app

System requirements:
macOS 10.13.6